# What is the time complexity of element access for boost::hana::tuple?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, template-meta-programming, random-access, boost-hana

As far as I can tell, for purely functional sequence types the naive implementation of a sequence would result in O(n) time complexity for element access and a better implementation (as described by [Chris Okasaki](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.5156)) enjoys O(log n) complexity, for a sequence of length n.

What is the time complexity of accessing an arbitrary element in a `boost::hana::tuple` with `operator[]`? If it's neither of the above, how is it implemented?

Comment: if as said in documentation boost::hana is conceptually similar to `std::tuple` it would be O(1)

Comment: I don't see why it would be anything but O(1) (at runtime).

Comment: Run time or compile time?

Comment: The documentation's graph "Runtime behaviour of transform" (https://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-performance) suggests O(1) to me, else the graph for `hana::tuple` would end up veering off exponentially, right? We can basically just compare against `std::array`'s complexity here, I think ... assuming `transform` requires at least N `op[]`s (which it does!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime complexity is O(1). Basically, it's as fast as accessing a struct member (because that's essentially what it is). The implementation is similar to a `std::tuple`.

As for the compile-time complexity, it's also O(1), but you do pay O(n) compile-time complexity for creating the tuple at the beginning. Also, here, I measure compile-time complexity in terms of the number of template instantiations, but that's a very naive way of measuring the final compilation time.

**Edit:** Here's the gist of how tuple access works:

```
// Holds an element of the tuple
template <std::size_t n, typename Xn>
struct elt { Xn data_; };

// Inherits multiply from the holder structs
template <typename Indices, typename ...Xn>
struct tuple_impl;

template <std::size_t ...n, typename ...Xn>
struct tuple_impl<std::index_sequence<n...>, Xn...>
    : elt<n, Xn>...
{ /* ... */ };

template <typename ...Xn>
struct basic_tuple
    : tuple_impl<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Xn)>, Xn...>
{ /* ... */ };

// When you call get<n>(tuple), your tuple is basically casted to a reference
// to one of its bases that holds a single element at the right index, and then
// that element is accessed.
template <std::size_t n, typename Xn>
Xn const& get(elt<n, Xn> const& xn)
{ return xn.data_; }
```

Comment: Can you sketch out how O(1) compile-time complexity is achieved? I can see that for a fixed-length sequence you could implement an accessor for each element (e.g. `get0`, `get1`, ..., `getn`) to achieve O(1) complexity. But if the length is *not* known until a template is instantiated, how do you do it?

Comment: Very clever! This part is a bit tricky, can you clarify? When you call e.g. `get<1>(tuple)` the compiler tries to deduce what the second template parameter could be, and since `basic_tuple` only inherits from one class of type `elt<1, /* something */>` then `Xn` is deduced to be `/* something */`?

Comment: Or is this right? During name-lookup the appropriate `get<1, T>` is considered because each of the tuple's base classes is added to the candidate set. And then during template parameter deduction only one can be selected since we explicitly specified `n`.